# How to get the function type of a constructor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function to get the pure function type of a constructor, an example is as follows:

```js
interface SomeConstructor {
    new (name: string): number;
    age: number;
}

// The desired tool function to be written
type GetFunctionFromConstructor<T> = ???

// Hope to get the results
type Ret = GetFunctionFromConstructor<SomeConstructor> // Ret: (name: string) => number
```

This question is not one that I encountered in actual development, but rather a curiosity that arose while I was reading an article about TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the help of `ConstructorParameters` and `InstanceType`.

```
interface SomeConstructor {
  new (name: string): number;
  age: number;
}

// The desired tool function to be written
type GetFunctionFromConstructor<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any> =
  (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>;

// Hope to get the results
type Ret = GetFunctionFromConstructor<SomeConstructor> // Ret: (name: string) => number
```

Assuming `T` is a constructor (as we have enforced by extending `new (...args: any) => any`), `ConstructorParameters<T>` gives us a tuple describing the constructor parameters, while `InstanceType<T>` gives the instance type (which is corresponds to the return type of the constructor).

When I hovered over `Ret`, I got the desired result: "type Ret = (name: string) => number"

Comment: This does indeed yield the correct result, but there will be an error warning

Comment: Type 'SomeConstructor' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: unknown[]) => unknown'.
  Types of parameters 'name' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2344)

Comment: @Autumn Odd. I was writing it at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript and didn't get any errors. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Autumn I changed `unknown` to `any`—that fixed it (tested it in VSCode this time just to make sure). I updated the answer as well.